Downloading image in Chromium browser to local Windows 10 folder via drag and drop isn't permitted
Given the 2 images below, why is it that I can drag and drop the first one to a local folder on my PC, but the second one will not allow it. Tested on Chrome, Brave, Opera and Edge.
Also, if you open image in new tab, the first one is shown centered in the window, while the second one is shown aligned top-left to the browser frame.
The second image is a hotlink from Telegram's CDN. Are they doing something sever-side that causes the browser to handle their images differently?
Right click -> Save image as... works as expected for both images.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

On what system? I get a clear error on Windows 10, unrelated to your suspicion - look at the file name length. I'd say it stands out quite a lot from the other one.

I'm on Windows 10 also. It fails silently. Yes it's definitely a long URL. Seems like this is something either the browser of the OS should be prepared to deal with.

I got this error shown when I drag it in latest Windows 10:

Which of course indicates filename problems and that is definitely related to allowed length.
P_DjfFnzHz1ghVrQK2v0xuusZBSPdqzoo_Pelvb1l1eU7VNuS8pINui1xrfMhcCJfsYzhzV_dv9y3E9fAy2hZ85hmX5VZ9QF0f32ZYnmyA5WHtKCQeS2E_WWSNYPvmtHgtgRRnk1S2uXsDfSy_-v86uT5W9w4vC4MvMdkkHmi777HH-BMSUWXYZARwn30ELEcded1208V6WzFJJCRVsUU4FPTrA-i1ldzWm4fP7pugmdBaO2ehgYnlP6KWMEOPUtvj3VWKAcFSUvjh4af5wQOjOWD9UJZS5JYQbupzs1rJE78RuednPXpvIDbCk3YZ6W4ScNxgbRokpuLjhduHyLcQ.jpg is the filename set by Telegram.
P_DjfFnzHz1ghVrQK2v0xuusZBSPdqzoo_Pelvb1l1eU7VNuS8pINui1xrfMhcCJfsYzhzV_dv9y3E9fAy2hZ85hmX5VZ9QF0f32ZYnmyA5WHtKCQeS2E_WWSNYPvmtHgtgRRnk1S2uXsDfSy_-v86uT5W9w4vC4MvMdkkHmi777HH-BMSUWXYZARwn30ELEcded1208V6WzFJJCRVsUU4FP.jpg is what the save dialog shortens it to when you go for that option.
Chrome forgot to implement a similar feature for drag and drop and there's nothing you can do about it except maybe filling a Chromium bug report.

See also docs about limits. Note that there's a mention of a registry entry you could modify to enable longer paths, but it's not supported by Explorer to this day.

Thanks for the analysis. Maybe I don't have the latest system update. My registry does already have the key for longer pathnames enabled, but yeah that seems to do nothing. For some reason the copy operation just fails without any error shown.

Maybe because you have the registry entry it hides the error, but Explorer can't still handle it.
